# How to merge small blocks of a file in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We plan to `append` data to our files in `NEW_BLOCK` mode. This gives us more flexibility as to DN status.
Now after running the process for days, we find our 2mb file has too many blocks.

Is there a way to merge the blocks of a file - say bring down the 100 blocks for a file to 4.

Comment: Can you not block appends and copy file to new name?